# Extract info from file

Tags: c, file-io

I have a file that contains emails.
The format is

```
< email: sender1@hotmail.com >
1111 2222 3333 aaaa
</email>
< email: sender2@gov.gr>
aaabbbbb cccccc
</email>
```

and I want to save in variables some info (senders , message and number of emails)

my code is like that

```
   FILE *fp;
   char line[150];

   fp= fopen("a.txt", "r");

   if (fp==NULL)
          error ("opening file");
   else{
          while (!feof(fp))
          {
             fscanf(fp, "%s", line);
             printf("%s\n", line);

            // does C support regular expressions ???
          }
   }
```

Comment: What happens if one of the emails includes the text `"</email>"` in its body?

Answer (score 2):

[Regular Expression Matching in C](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).